Expo how to set <appAuthRedirectScheme> if app is not ejected?
I get the following error when building my Expo app:
Android build failed with 'no value for <appAuthRedirectScheme> is provided'
Is there any way to set this without ejecting the whole app to edit the manifest files?
I tried adding the following to the app.json but still get the same error:
"intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "com.limislogger.app"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },


I faced the same issue, and it's currently a bug with Expo.
The only work around I could find was to use patch-project to retrospectively apply a patch to build.gradle after the build process has created the android folder.
This post on Github gives steps: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/2322#issuecomment-2098588800
